# Why does my json string have 28 unprintable characters in it?

Tags: json, jsp

I am producing a JSON string from a database query in JSP but it always has unprintable characters in it and I don't understand why!

The JSP to produce the JSON is below:

```
  String user = "username"; // set a username
  String password = "password"; // set a password
  Class.forName("org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver"); // JDBC for firebird a.k.a. Jaybird
  String DB = "jdbc:firebirdsql://123.123.123.123:3050/C:\\db.fdb";

  JSONArray obj=new JSONArray(); //Creating the json object

    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB, user, password);              
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

  int i=0;
  Class.forName("org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver"); // JDBC for firebird a.k.a. Jaybird
  String query = "SELECT ses.sessionid, ses.datetime, ses.guid, ses.staffid FROM session ses ORDER by ses.datetime";
  ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery(query);

  while (resultset.next())
    {
    JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
    j.put("SessionID", resultset.getString("sessionid"));
    j.put("DateTime", resultset.getString("datetime"));
    j.put("GUID", resultset.getString("guid"));
    j.put("StaffID", resultset.getString("staffid"));
    obj.add(i, j);
    i++; // Counter for indexing the JSONArray
  }

  resultset.close();
  statement.close();
  connection.close();
```

And this is the code I am using in PHP to display:

```
    echo '*'.$json.'*<br>';
    echo strlen($json).'<br>';
    $json = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $json);
    echo '*'.$json.'*<br>';
    echo strlen($json).'<br>';
```

which shows:

```
* [{"SessionID":"850","DateTime":"2011-10-03 14:21:37.0","GUID":"51e71c19-ca13-4053-bd95-2addb5ba69f6","StaffID":"804"}] *
146
*[{"SessionID":"850","DateTime":"2011-10-03 14:21:37.0","GUID":"51e71c19-ca13-4053-bd95-2addb5ba69f6","StaffID":"804"}]*
118
```

So a difference of 28 unprintable characters - mostly at the beginning. How are they getting there and how can I get rid of them in the JSP?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because JSP is as being a view technology part of the HTTP response. Everything outside `<% %>` is sent to the response as well, including whitespace and newlines (rightclick the HTML page produced by PHP, do *View Source* and you'll see those newlines yourself as well, it are those newlines which you account to "unprintable" characters).

Remove any whitespace and newlines outside `<% %>` or, better, use a [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) instead. You can find some kickoff examples of a JSON-producing Servlet in the answer to [How to use Servlets and Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax)

Comment: Thanks for the response. There isn't that much whitespace and most is coming from the "@page import"'s which I have no control over. Is a servlet the only way as that means re-writing all my code.

Comment: Just remove any whitespace between `%>` and `<%` including newlines. You don't need to rewrite all code. Just copypasting into `doGet()` method is fine. You only need to prepare `out` yourself as `response.getWriter()`. Writing Java code in a JSP file instead of a Java class is a poor practice anyway. Just never do that. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files